# Delegates and multicast delegates in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, delegates

What are Delegates and Multicast Delegates in VB.NET? How do I use them?

Please provide a simple example to illustrate the concept.

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx) has plenty of examples.